# How to add Tab Bar Item to UiTabbarController without link with UiView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

1.In storyboard i have 1 Tab Bar Controller(not Tab Bar) link with 4 View.

2.I want to add Tab Bar Item without link with view. 
  Because i want to click it's and do something (not open view).

3.I Can't drag and drop Tab Bar Item to Tab Bar Controller.
  (if i use Tab Bar on view i can drag and drop but i don't want it's)

4.How to add Tab Bar Item to UiTabbarController without link with UiView?

this is part of controller class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   if(self.ArID.length > 0)
        self.ArInfo = [self QueryArWithParamID:self.ArID];

   csArController *ar = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
   ar.ArInfo = self.ArInfo;

   csSaleRemainController *remain = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
   remain.ArID = self.ArInfo.ID;

   csArMapController *armap = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
   armap.ArInfo = self.ArInfo;

   csSaleHistoryController *salehis = [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:4];
   salehis.ArID = self.ArInfo.ID;

   self.selectedViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.SelectedTab intValue]];
}
```